# How to automate apt upgrade options?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

When you run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` on a new Ubuntu installation, you are prompted by a series of options where a pink screen pops up over the CLI and asks whether you want to 'Keep current settings?' etc.

I am considering automating this in a bash script which proceeds to install a few additional tools which are desirable on every fresh instance used by the company. So a developer can simply pull a bash script from git and run one script to perform `update`, `upgrade` and then the meat of the installations the team needs on each fresh box.

How can I have the script take care of the pink pop ups with perhaps an option similar to the `apt install -y` style 'y' flag to click the default on each pink prompt?

Comment: Did you actually try that -y flag with apt? If that does not do it, then use apt-get -y instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please use for these the `debconf-set-selections`   more here [man pages of debconf-set-selections](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/debconf-set-selections.1.html)

Also you can have an example for the mysql-server installation [install mysql-server without a password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-a-password-prompt)